# How to install virtualbox on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, wine

using Ubuntu 14.04

1. I **download** the Ubuntu version from this link:

   https://virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

   Ubuntu 13.04/13.10/14.04 (64bit)

   http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.18/virtualbox-4.3_4.3.18-96516~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb
2. **installed** with terminal like explained here

   ```
   wget -q https:// virtualbox .org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

cause it doesn't run I try new way

1. I **download** the windows version:

   https://virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
   http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.18/VirtualBox-4.3.18-96516-Win.exe
2. **install** it by using "Wine"

   > Error window: SUPR3HardenedMain Effective UID is not root (euid=1000
   >   egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000) (rc=-10) Please try reinstalling
   >   VirtualBox.

Any other idea or way to do it? cant find why is not working!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Virtualbox is available from the Ubuntu repository. You can install it from the Ubuntu Software Center or using the terminal by running `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

If you need the Oracle maintained VirtualBox run this in the Terminal:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 
'$(lsb_release -cs)' contrib non-free' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list" && 
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-
key add - && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3 dkms
```

Answer (score 4):

Virtualbox can be installed by simple

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

But before running this command you should sync canonical by software updater on Other option.

Comment: While this is certianly more convenient, it will always get you an older version from what is available.

Answer (score 1):

cd to the folder to which you downloaded the virtualbox package.

Actually you install the package with:

```
sudo dpkg --install virtualbox-4.3_4.3.18-96516~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

--> Download the Virtual Machine for Ubuntu version from this link:

**https://virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads**

--> Now if your setup is being downloaded in Downloads folder (any folder it can get downloaded and check the folder and then give the name accordingly) then follow this command:

**cd Downloads**

--> Now follow this command:

**sudo apt-get install virtualbox**

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt